# Need to transfer a column's data. I have 2 sheets with same data and need to move corresponding data from one to another

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, vlookup, search-indexing

I have 2 excel sheets and both have one column that has matching data. However *Sheet2* has a column of data that *Sheet1* does not have and I need to input the corresponding data from *Sheet2* into *Sheet1* to complete it.

Match cell data in `column B` on *Sheet2* to a cell in `column B` *Sheet1*.

Upon match, cell data from corresponding cell in `column C` *Sheet2* inputs to *column C* in *Sheet1*.

**Sheet 1**:

```
System     Supplier Part Number      Company Part Number    Description
11120      V496-3-405                                       roller
11130      N554546                                          wheel
11140      N324560                                          bushing
11150      N145856                                          bearing
11160      N123456                                          castor
11170      4547876                                          spacer
11180      2000045                                          switch
etc        etc                                              etc
```

**Sheet 2:**

```
Company Part Number           Supplier Part Number
100235                        N123456
100500                        N145856
120050                        N324560
130500                        V496-3-405
160075                        2000045
170050                        4547876
180050                        N554546
etc                           etc
```

Comment: `=INDEX(Sheet2!A:A,MATCH(B2,Sheet2!B:B,0))` in C2 and auto-fill down will do it

Comment: Your question doesn't match your example.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the function [VLOOKUP](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1).

Syntax: `VLOOKUP (lookup_value, table_array, col_index_num, [range_lookup])`

With Vlookup you can search for a match and bring the value in another cell of the same row of the match.

To make it work, you need to exchange columns on **Sheet2** so it should look like this:

```
Supplier Part Number     Company Part Number
N123456                  100235
N145856                  100500
N324560                  120050
V496-3-405               130500
2000045                  160075
4547876                  170050
N554546                  180050
etc                      etc
```

Now, in **Sheet1** cell `C2`you must put: `=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!A:B,2,FALSE)`.

It will look for a match of the value of `A2` in the first column of the range `Sheet2!A:B`, and bring the content of column `2` of that range (`Company Part Number`).

`FALSE` means that it will look for the exact match.